# Image path confusion in Angular2 example

Tags: angular

Referring to

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lDNJVOGAjk5SLft2JmOp?p=info)

In ***app.component.ts***, *imagePath* is defined at ***angular.png***,
However, in the **codebase** the image is actually named as ***angular.base64.png***.

```
 <img [src]="imagePath">
```

How is the image still appearing ?

Answer (score 1):

OK consider this,

Q: Can you create a folder named **MyImages** in given plunker?
A: Yes

Q: How?
A: Cick on the ***New File***, a window popup will be asking for folder name, give it a name like **MyImages**.

*So far so good.*

Q: Now how about inserting or adding an image into **MyImages** folder? Is it possible?
A: I wonder I don't know how.

**Note**: *In plunker adding an image into a folder is not as simple as adding image in windows-7/8/10* (try out yourself and check whether it is that easy?).

So question to your answer is,

***.base64.png only shows/indicates base64 encoded file with .png extension. So it is just an image file encoded in base64. That's it.***

And rest thing is as simple as using plunker. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a Plunker feature. Plunker doesn't allow to upload binary files but you can base64-encode a file and add it as text file with `name.base64.ext` and the iframe where the code runs gets access to the data using a `name.ext` URL.